# The for-attribute on labels in jQuery forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile

Regarding forms with labeled fields, [this (out-dated) jQuery Mobile documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/forms/docs-forms.html) states:

> Be sure to pair them properly with label elements via the *for* attribute.

The *for* attribute still exists in the latest version, but [the current documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/) does not even mention it anymore. What is it used for? Some sort of form validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's standard HTML (not jQm-specific) used to link text with a corresponding input element.

[MDN Docs for `<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Example:

```
<label for="your_name">Your Name:</label>
<input id="your_name" value="John Smith" />
```

When I tap on the label, the input text will gain focus. The `for` attribute should be set to the ID of the input element.

Comment: True, but if you enclose the input element in its label, the for attribute is not needed.

Comment: @kennebec Good point, and that's a valid usage as per the MDN docs, however I have experienced odd behavior on desktop browsers (can't remember which one) using that syntax.

Comment: So its sole purpose is "When [user taps] on the label, the input text will gain focus."? Nothing else?

Comment: @Domi Correct, although third party party scripts may use the attribute for finding out which text represents an input